# Looping(?) an if statement

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm a noob to shell scripting and am wondering about this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
number=5
echo "Enter 'yes' to continue, 'no' to abort:"
read choice
if [ $choice = yes ]; then
        while [ $number -lt 10 ]; do
                echo "The script is now looping!"
        done
elif [ $choice = no ]; then
        echo "Loop aborted"
else
        echo "Please say 'yes' or 'no'"
        read choice
# What now?
fi
```

How would I go about the if statement rechecking your $choice (On line 13) if you do not specify "yes" or "no"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can put the code from "echo Enter..." till fi in an outer "while" loop. The while loop would loop until $choice is "yes" or "no". Remove the last "else" clause while doing this (it would be redundant).
2. P.S. you need to increment (or change) $number in your inner while loop. Otherwise, it will run infinitely.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep track of whether to loop in a variable called `invalid_choice`

```
invalid_choice=true
while $invalid_choice; do
    read choice
    if [ "$choice" = "yes" ]; then
        invalid_choice=false
        ...
    elif [ "$choice" = "no" ]; then
        invalid_choice=false
        ...
    else
        echo "Please say yes or no"
done
```

Or you could generalize it into a function if you need to do this a lot:

```
function confirm() {
    local ACTION="$1"
    read -p "$ACTION (y/n)? " -n 1 -r -t 10 REPLY
    echo ""
    case "$REPLY" in
        y|Y ) return 0 ;;
        *   ) return 1 ;;
    esac
}

confirm "Do something dangerous" || exit
```